# I am uploading file with DiskFileItemFactory.But file is not uploading using Java

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to upload file using java web application using `DiskFileItemFactory`.But the problem is it was not getting any file.It shows empty array in iteration.

`iter.size()` is 0.
See below of my code.

```
public ModelAndView upload( ModelMap model, HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException, FileUploadException {
if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {

    System.out.println("file available");
}

boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
if (isMultipart) {
    //  ResourceImpl resource = new ResourceImpl();
    try {
        //Create a factory for disk-based file items
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
        System.out.println(items.size());
        Iterator iter = items.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {

            FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

My form is;

```jsp
 <form method="post" action="/DropBox/upload.html" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     Select file to upload: <input type="file" name="uploadFile" />
     <br/><br/>
     <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
 </form>
```

Where I am doing wrong.
plaese help me.
thanq.

Comment: Now check it problem to here  List items = upload.parseRequest(request).Shows 0 siz.

Comment: Does it make a difference, if you declare the list using using a generic type such as `List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);`? BTW this is a detailed [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2424824/1391249) about uploading files using the Servlet API.

Comment: Hi.. Tiny.I have tried with generic type.But it is also showing same result.

Comment: If it is Spring MVC (given the impression by the return type `ModelAndView` of one of the methods in your code) then, there a [facility](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart) out of the box to upload multipart contents. There is no need to repeat the same code.

Comment: So what i have to do....?

Comment: Yup! learning lessons like me :) You need to configure [`org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartResolver.html) in your Spring config file (may be named `disparcher-servlet.xml`) Google could give you examples [such as](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/).

Comment: Ya I have configured that......that is not a problem to here.

Comment: That should be working then :) Does it?

Answer (score 0):

You should try for each. it does well.

```
if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {

    try {
        List<FileItem> multipart = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);

        for (FileItem item : multipart) {

            if (!item.isFormField()) {

                filename = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                folder = "path";
                File file = new File(folder);

                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.mkdir();

                }
            }

            item.write(new File(folder + "/" + filename));
        }
    }
}
```